# composer.phar install older packages

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a problem with "Composer"
When I use Composer from my notebook with Linux operating system, Composer install older versions of components than those installed.
When I use Composer from my Windows PC in the office everything works fine (using the same "composer.phar" file under version control).

What could be the problem? The command I use is `php composer.phar update` from project directory.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: Please submit a bug report with full information (composer.json, PHP/OS versions, ..) or ask on IRC or the mailing list. stackoverflow isn't really the best medium for debugging issues.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is because you have a `composer.lock` file on your linux machine. Composer has two main commands: `install` and `update`.

Install will check if a `composer.lock` file is present. If it is, that file will be used to determine which versions of the dependencies to install. If not, it will implicitly do an `update` to get the latest matching versions.

Update will always try to get the latest matching versions and then write those into the `composer.lock` file.

The suggestion here would be to:

- Commit your `composer.lock` into version control (remove it from `.gitignore`).
- Run `composer update` on your linux machine to get the latest versions.

Comment: Oh well, in that case please consult IRC.